# Filter a List using values from drop down menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

Okay, I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing, but my boss wanted me to build something basic for his techs to use when sizing up an air conditioning job. I've got 4 drop menus to use as filters and I've got values for all possible results. I can't figure how to implement the filters and make it show all the criteria entered into the fields.

What I have so far:

```
<form>

Tonnage
<select id="Tonnage" onchange="Tonnage()">
  <option>Any</option>
  <option>1.5 Ton</option>
  <option>2 Ton</option>  
  <option>2.5 Ton</option>
  <option>3 Ton</option>
  <option>3.5 Ton</option>
  <option>4 Ton</option>
  <option>5 Ton</option>
</select>
</form>

<form>
SEER
<select id="SEER" onchange="SEER()">
  <option>Any</option>
  <option>13</option>
  <option>14</option>
  <option>15</option>  
  <option>16</option>
  <option>17</option>
  <option>18</option>
  <option>20</option>
</select>
</form>

<form>
Manufacturer
<select id="Manufacturer" onchange="Manufacturer()">
  <option>Any</option>
  <option>Amana</option>
  <option>Bryant</option>  
  <option>Carrier</option>
  <option>Goodman</option>
  <option>Nordyne</option>
  <option>Payne</option>
  <option>Ruud</option>
  <option>Trane</option>
</select>
</form>

<form>
Unit Type
<select id="Type" onchange="Type()">
  <option>Any</option>
  <option>Split Heat Pump</option>
  <option>Packaged Heat Pump</option>
</select>
</form>

</form>
<script>

//Amana 1.5 Ton Options
<div class="result" data-Tonnage="1.5" data-Manufacturer="Amana" data-SEER="13" data-Type="Split Heat Pump"</div>
<div class="result" data-Tonnage="1.5" data-Manufacturer="Amana" data-SEER="13" data-Type="Packaged Heat Pump"</div>
<div class="result" data-Tonnage="1.5" data-Manufacturer="Amana" data-SEER="14" data-Type="Split Heat Pump"</div>
<div class="result" data-Tonnage="1.5" data-Manufacturer="Amana" data-SEER="14" data-Type="Packaged Heat Pump"</div>
<div class="result" data-Tonnage="1.5" data-Manufacturer="Amana" data-SEER="15" data-Type="Split Heat Pump"</div>
<div class="result" data-Tonnage="1.5" data-Manufacturer="Amana" data-SEER="15" data-Type="Packaged Heat Pump"</div>
<div class="result" data-Tonnage="1.5" data-Manufacturer="Amana" data-SEER="16" data-Type="Split Heat Pump"</div>
<div class="result" data-Tonnage="1.5" data-Manufacturer="Amana" data-SEER="16" data-Type="Packaged Heat Pump"</div>
<div class="result" data-Tonnage="1.5" data-Manufacturer="Amana" data-SEER="17" data-Type="Split Heat Pump"</div>
<div class="result" data-Tonnage="1.5" data-Manufacturer="Amana" data-SEER="17" data-Type="Packaged Heat Pump"</div>
<div class="result" data-Tonnage="1.5" data-Manufacturer="Amana" data-SEER="18" data-Type="Split Heat Pump"</div>
<div class="result" data-Tonnage="1.5" data-Manufacturer="Amana" data-SEER="18" data-Type="Packaged Heat Pump"</div>
<div class="result" data-Tonnage="1.5" data-Manufacturer="Amana" data-SEER="20" data-Type="Split Heat Pump"</div>
<div class="result" data-Tonnage="1.5" data-Manufacturer="Amana" data-SEER="20" data-Type="Packaged Heat Pump"</div>
```

I've got divs for nearly 800 more results. Is this even possible using javascript or is there a better option out there? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is set the value of the option the in the select tag add the onchange to output that value to a page ex:

```
<select id="Manufacturer" onchange="Manufacturer(this.value)">
<option value="foo">Foo</option>
</select>
```

The Manufacturer function:

```
function Manufacturer(value) {
 document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=value
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I get the value in the option, but the function thing in the second box is kinda throwing me. Where does that go?

Comment: nevermind, figured it out./facepalm. Thanks amillion!